# WSO2 API Manager server managing users using API

Tags: api, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I need to create/remove and manage users in WSO2 AM 2.0.0 through API. Is there any way of managing users and roles without the WSO2 carbon (or store) user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` SOAP service for this.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs

Comment: I am getting error: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication Failed : Invalid remote address passed - myapp
When trying to run sample code from https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs.
What does APP_ID = "myapp" mean?

Comment: It should be APP_ID="localhost".

Comment: Probably APP_ID is personal and depends on your config, you may check you service provider tables like described here: docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Service+Provider+Related+Tables